# Cannot read theme properties of styled-components during gatsby build

Tags: gatsby, styled-components

I am trying to build a site in Gatsby styled with styled-components.

Running `gatsby develop` shows the page fine but when I try the build the page, I get the following error:

**Error**

```
Building static HTML failed for path "/Page/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  16 |     font-family: Lack;
  17 |     text-align: center;
> 18 |     background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.purple};
     |                                                 ^
  19 |     color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};
  20 |   }
  21 | `;


  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'purple' of undefined
```

**Layout.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../theme/theme';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  * {
    @import url('Lack-Regular.otf');
  }
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
`;

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle theme={theme} />
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  </>
);

export default Layout;
```

**Toast.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import React from 'react';
import { ToastContainer, Bounce } from 'react-toastify';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const WrappedToastContainer = ({ className, ...rest }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <ToastContainer {...rest} />
  </div>
);

const StyledContainer = styled(WrappedToastContainer).attrs({
})`
  .Toastify__toast {
    font-family: Lack;
    text-align: center;
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.purple}; // theme props undefined here.
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};
  }
`;

const Toast = () => (
  <StyledContainer
    closeButton={false}
    position="bottom-center"
    autoClose={3000}
    hideProgressBar
    newestOnTop={false}
    closeOnClick={false}
    rtl={false}
    pauseOnFocusLoss={false}
    draggable={false}
    pauseOnHover={false}
    transition={Bounce}
  />
);

export default Toast;
```

**gatsby info --clipboard**

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 11.3.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.1.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/bin/node
    npm: 7.11.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.1.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Firefox: 88.0.1
    Safari: 14.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^3.4.1 => 3.4.2
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^4.4.0 => 4.4.0
    gatsby-plugin-styled-components: ^4.4.0 => 4.4.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 3.4.1
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'AddisonWebsite',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-styled-components',
      options: {
        // Add any options here
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "addison-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "AddisonWebsite",
  "author": "Addison",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.4.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

This error is fairly new to me since I have been using Gatsby + styled-components for awhile now and my builds usually work fine with the above set up. I even have a site that I build recently with near identical files as above.

I understand this might have something do with the SSR but I'm not sure what is wrong with the above.

How can I build my site with `gatsby build` with the theme provider passing the props properly?

Answer (score 5):

You probably supplied the theme by using the `wrapRootElement` API in `gatsby-browser.js`. During build time, Gatsby will instead execute the code from `gatsby-ssr.js`. This is also explained [in the Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#usage).

In most cases it should be sufficient to simply copy all code from `gatsby-browser.js` to `gatsby-ssr.js` or move common code to another file and import it in both API files.

Comment: Thanks, this was it for me. I'm using `shouldUpdateScroll` in my browser file, but that's throwing an error in my cli. Do know if removing this from the ssr file will cause any issues? IIRC, gatsby docs stay browser and srr files should not differ